# Backbone.js base 64 encoding?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, base64

This is a very specifc case, but I don't want to have to the re-write the Javascript for an entire feature. Is there a way to make every HTTP request base 64 encoded in Backbone.js? It's preventing the saving of an object in Firefox which is unfortunately the test environment we have to use. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some example code or explain more about the error you are running into?

Comment: Sure, basically when a request is sent Firefox renders the popup "This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend  the form data you have typed to the new location?". I've Googled it and all signs point to disabling all add-ons, which I've tried to do but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `Backbone.sync` and have it do whatever you want when saving.  Specifically lines `1331` and `1332` in the source for 0.92 deal with what encoding you're sending to the server and how to get the model data in that.

You could just copy `Backbone.sync` wholesale out of backbone in to your project and make your modifications there.

You're going to need a library to perform the base64 encoding obviously, but you could do something like:

```
  params.contentType = 'base64';
  params.data = base64.encode(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON()));
```

(Where obviously `base64` is an object provided by your code)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm now overriding the sync method and base 64 encoding the params right before the the final AJAX call is made. The only problem now is that it doesn't seem to be rendering the data anymore. Is there a place in the Backbone code that you can decode the return?

Comment: You'd do this in the `parse` method of your model. The parameter to `parse` is the server resp, and it expects a javascript object with all the values set.  If you need more help than this, you should ask a second question.  Also, if this worked for you don't forget to accept and upvote :)